# Using a font resource from another assembly

Tags: wpf, fonts, resources, label, resourcedictionary

Currently, I have a class library project that contains themes/templates and fonts (as resources). I am then referencing that project, named Shared.UI, in my main WPF application project.

I am referencing it using the:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Shared.UI;component/Skin.xaml" />
```

within a MergedDictionary tag.

The issue that I'm having is that the main WPF application isn't able to use the fonts from the project where they are built as resources.

In my Shared.UI/Skins.xaml file, I have:

```
<!-- LABEL -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./resources/#Helvetica Neue" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

I assume that this isn't working in my main WPF application because it looks in its own `./resources` for the `#Helvetica Neue` and fails to find it (because it's in Shared.UI). I tried to also explicitly reference the `/Shared.UI;component/resources/#Helvetica Neue` within the resource file but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link, hope it helps
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/068d9600-93e6-45e4-af37-2b04e4b41855/how-to-load-a-font-from-a-resource-only-dll-in-c

```
<TextBlock><Run FontFamily="/FontClassLibrary;Component/#YourFontName" FontSize="20">Your Text</Run></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, if the link goes dead, your answer will still be useful. You also need to explain ***how*** this answers the question and why it will solve this problem.

Comment: Is there any way that I can define that in a Style or do I need to always have that RUN tag in there for the font to appear correctly? If I had to go about doing this in every single control, I would probably just import the font into the main project... It just seems a lot less extensible.

Comment: Bah, then it is just easier and cleaner to copy the `fonts` folder to the specific project.